# Null value when posting data from a html form to a c# controller method using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am teaching myself how to program and I am having a hard time identifying an issue with my most recent experiment. The following is within the context of an 'ASP.NET Web Application (.NetFramework) C#' and MVC architecture.

I am attempting to post data from a html form to a c# controller method using a JavaScript function.

The JavaScript function invokes the controller method; however, the string passed to the method always has a null value. (I know that the new 'Organisation' instance is successfully created, as new instances appear with an ID in my database yet with a null name - as per my model).

I have searched similar questions and tested `contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8` also; however, my issue persists.

The error reads: `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s'` and occurs at `var jsonDataParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonData);` in my c# controller method.

I was hoping someone may be kind enough to help me :)

The form:

```
<form id="createOrganisationForm">

    <label for="organisationName">Organisation name</label>
    <input type="text" id="organisationName" />

    <input type="submit" onclick="createOrganisation()" value="submit" />

</form>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function createOrganisation() {

    var formData = {
        "OrganisationName": $("#organisationName").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOrganisation", "Organisations")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })

}
```

The c# method in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreateOrganisation(string jsonData)
{
    var jsonDataParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    var organisationName = jsonDataParsed["OrganisationName"].ToString();

    var organisation = new Organisation();
    organisation.Name = organisationName;
    db.Organisations.Add(organisation);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The model:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try removing  JSON.stringify

Comment: @viveknuna I have just tested ```data: formdata``` as per your suggestion; unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Try creating a class lets day ABC with property OrganisationName. And in the post method use parameter ABC in place of string

Comment: @viveknuna Thank you, although I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. I suspect my issue must be something to do with the stringify invocation, content type or parsing.

Comment: Please give s try

Comment: So either use [FromBody] string param or use a ABC param (where ABC is class name)

Comment: jQuery.ajax eats live objects as data, don't stringify the object. Also you've to prevent the form submission, otherwise the form is submitted, and the AJAX call in aborted. This is why you're gettin `null`at the server.

Comment: @viveknuna Thank you I have tried using ```[FromBody] string```; this has had no effect.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, does this mean I cannot achieve the intended behaviour?

Comment: No, ofcourse not. You've to listen the submit event of the form instead of listening clicks on the submit button, or change the type of the button to `button`. Then you can prevent the default action of the event. Notice, that servers are regocnizing the data in a form based on their `name` attribute, `id` is not used for this.

Comment: @Teemu Oh thank you, I understand now. I'll report back in a moment :)

Comment: @Teemu I have changed my input to ```<input type="text" id="organisationName" name="organisationName" />```, I have changed my submit input to ```<button onclick="createOrganisation()">Submit</button>``` and have changed data to ```data: formData```. I am still receiving the error; however, I think your suggestions will lead to the answer after I have conducted a little more research.

Comment: The form is still submitted, the type of the button must explicitly be set to `button`, the default action of an untyped button in a form is submitting the form. The data was not found from the submitted form at the server probably because `organisationName !== OrganisationName`. Case-sensitivity is environment-specific, though.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you! I've set  type=button and am no longer receiving the error. I can now progress. Thank you everyone else for your suggestions too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function createOrganisation() {

    var formData = {
        "OrganisationName": $("#organisationName").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOrganisation", "Organisations")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'formData': formData }
    })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have just tried changing ```data: JSON.stringify(formData)``` to ```data: {'formData': formData }```. Unfortunately I get an identical error :(

Comment: Please try this with your code :  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: Thank you, as per my description I have already tested this with no luck, sorry!

Comment: I have just copied your code, and for me if I click on Submit, `formData` is shown as undefined :-

Comment: thank you for helping me out Mr. R. Check out the suggestions by Teemu above - I'm no longer having this issue after some alterations to my form and JS function :)

Comment: @juststressed Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. Special thanks go to @Teemu for pointing me towards the final solution.

Below is a working solution; I hope this may help others with future issues.

Key changes:

- `name="organisationName"` atrribute added to input
- `<input type="submit"` edited to `<button type="button"`
- `"parameter="` added to `data:` in ajax request
- `["OrganisationName"]` edited to `["organisationName"]` in C# method

Please refer to @Teemu advice in the question's comment section for the rationale behind these changes.

The HTML form:

```
<form id="createOrganisationForm">

    <label for="organisationName">Organisation name</label>
    <input type="text" id="organisationName" name="organisationName" />

    <button type="button" onclick="createOrganisation()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function createOrganisation() {

    var formData = JSON.stringify({ organisationName: $("#organisationName").val()})

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: "jsonData=" + formData,
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOrganisation", "Organisations")',
        type: "POST"
    })
}
```

*Helpful note: the above script should be in the view file (not an external file) if you are using a razor @URL.Action*

The c# controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreateOrganisation(string jsonData)
{
    var jsonDataParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    var organisationName = jsonDataParsed["organisationName"].ToString();

    var organisation = new Organisation();
    organisation.Name = organisationName;
    db.Organisations.Add(organisation);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```